# The page does not loads up when i'm using proxy in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm using a proxy to load up a page using selenium. The code works fine if I don't use the proxy but when I apply proxy the page doesn't load at all. This is my code:

```
    
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

PROXY = "IP:PORT"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
url = "https://whatismyipaddress.com/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: My router is blocking it as a malware attempt. So either you posted a dodgy proxy or are trying to be a naughty boy.

Comment: I copied this IP from a free proxy list from here  https://geonode.com/free-proxy-list/

Comment: But doesn't matter what the proxy is the page never loads up